# Ada minimal task synchronization (performance related)

Tags: performance, task, shared-memory, ada

For a hobby interpreter project I am looking for advice on a performance-related question regarding task synchronization. A scheduler must map new green tasks to real tasks, each of which holds its own linked list of green tasks.

The problem: How do I synchronize the addition of a green task to a running real task with the least overhead possible? In earlier tests I have found out that making the linked list a protected object slows down access to it from within its own real task tremendously. To give you an idea of how tight the interpreter loop is currently in the single-task version:

```
while not Is_Empty (Global_State.GTasks) loop
   Current_Task := Next (Global_State.GTasks);
   Global_State.Pram (Current_Task.PC).all (Global_State, Current_Task);
   Current_Task.PC := Current_Task.PC + 1;
   Update (Global_State.GTasks, Current_Task);
end loop;
```

(Update still copies but I can later get rid of that.)

My tests have indicated that even minimal changes to this loop can slow down interpretation tremendously. Imagine that instead of in Global_State, GTasks resides as a local variable in the task executing this loop. I *only* need to synchronize access to GTasks when the scheduler adds a new GTask from the *outside* the task which runs this loop.

What would you recommend in this situation?

Comment: Is "implementing" GTasks as a protected-object-wrapped linked list the only thing you've tried with this so far?

Comment: Given that we are talking about the performace of the implementation of various Ada constructs, the answer may depend upon your platform and compiler. You should probably include that information.

Comment: @Marc C: Regarding synchronization, yes, as I didn't want to optimize prematurely. But I've tried some other data structures like arrays. I'm using GNAT with gcc 4.6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(The following is contingent on my having a reasonable understanding of the question.)

If one can go forward with the "GTasks resides as a local variable in the the task" conjecture, then perhaps incorporating a conditional accept may work--I have no idea what the performance hit would be, it's just an idea.

```
while not Is_Empty (GTasks) loop
   Current_Task := Next (GTasks);
   Global_State.Pram (Current_Task.PC).all (Global_State, Current_Task);
   Current_Task.PC := Current_Task.PC + 1;
   Update (GTasks, Current_Task);

   select
      accept Accept_New_Task(Green_Task : Green_Task_Type) do
         Append(GTasks, Green_Task);
      end Accept_New_Task;
   else
      null;
   end select;
end loop;
```

Or perhaps only periodically check for new tasks, say, every so-many PC increments? (Again, no promises on the performance hit.)

```
while not Is_Empty (GTasks) loop
   Current_Task := Next (GTasks);
   Global_State.Pram (Current_Task.PC).all (Global_State, Current_Task);
   Current_Task.PC := Current_Task.PC + 1;
   Update (GTasks, Current_Task);

   if PC_Increments = Check_For_New_Tasks then
      select
         accept Accept_New_Task(Green_Task : Green_Task_Type) do
            Append(GTasks, Green_Task);
         end Accept_New_Task;
      else
         null;
      end select;
      PC_Increments := 0;
   else
      PC_Increments := PC_Increments + 1;
   end if;
end loop;
```

Comment: I like your second variant and will give it a try. It's a stack machine where it makes sense to check only every _n_ instructions for new green tasks. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Eric - As given in that second variant it will accept only a single new task with each check. You'll need to determine whether that's acceptable--is new task creation/registration spread out or bursty? If the latter you may want to loop over and clear all the queued Accept_New_Task calls.